# Как использовать встроенный в ноутбук wifi модуль на виртуальной машине Kali Linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, виртуальная-машина

Не могу понять как использовать встроенный wifi модуль в кали линукс на виртуалке

Comment: точно так же как и в любом другом дистрибутиве (главное отличие дистрибутива kali от всех остальных — это название). но совершенно по-разному в зависимости от используемой системы виртауализации.

Comment: @aleksandr я использую vm ware workstation 16 pro,можно пожалуйста ссылку на статью или форум если таковые есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При работе с Kali Linux через VirtualBox или VMware требуется использовать внешний WiFi модуль.

Но можешь попробовать так:

```
apt-get install wicd
service network-manager stop
update-rc.d network-manager disable
update-rc.d wicd enable
service wicd start
```

И перезагрузиться

Comment: какое-то обоснование своему мнению вы сможете привести? прямо в тексте ответа, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ну смотри, самое простое решение это купить внешний WiFi модуль, но если хочешь танцы с бубнами, тогда можешь погуглить данный вопрос или ознакомиться с решением проблемы [здесь](https://computer76.ru/2016/01/23/bcm43142-driver-in-kali-linux/) Я просто подключил внешний модуль и всё заработало, благо он у меня был.